# translate sql to linq extension method inner join with select group by

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

Good day,

Thanks for your time.

I want to get the latest messages of a chat table by userId and projectId and this is working fine

```
 select * from chatTable inner join 
 (select max(SendDate) maxtime,[ProjectId]   from [chatTable]       
group by [ProjectId])latest
on latest.maxtime=chatTable.SendDate and
latest.[ProjectId]=chatTable.[ProjectId]
order by SendDate
```

As you can see, I am getting  the latest messages from the chatTable , with a join that brings the latest project id and the latest message.

How can I have a linq with extension methods?

```
var messages= await _dbContext.chatTable.....
```

Thanks

Comment: Please share what is the linq attempts you have tried. There are many linq questions and resources out there to help with that. We can help correct your attempts

Comment: to tell you the truth I am really stuck here....

Comment: So you want to get each `ProjectId` with its maximum `SendDate` as a list ordered by `SendDate`? I don't get why you need to use `inner join` here.

Comment: I need to get all messages from the table chat ( you see, in wtsp for instance you just see a preview of the latest message in a chat). the inner join is to filter

Comment: @evvk, If my answer works to you. Pls accept that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well guys, it seems that linq entity framework has its advantages
this query is better and gets the latest message sent to the latest project

```
    var ultimos = await _dbContext.chatTable .GroupBy(item => item.ProjectId)
     .Select(group => new { pId= group.Key, latestMessage= group.OrderByDescending(r=>r.SendDate)
    .FirstOrDefault() })
     .ToListAsync();
```

and all the messages are inside the entity

Answer (score 1):

You can first query the inner part like below:

```
var latest= _dbContext.chatTable.GroupBy(x=>x.ProjectId).Select(x=>new {maxTime=x.Max(y=>y.SendDate), ProjectId=x.Key });
var res=(from ct in _dbContext.ChatTable 
join la in latest on la.maxTime equals ct.SendDate and la.ProjectId equals ct.ProjectId).ToList().OrderBy(x=>x.SendDate);
```

Answer (score 1):

This query should do what you want

```
_dbContext.ChatTable
    .GroupBy(c => c.ProjectId)
    .Select(g => g
        .OrderByDescending(c => c.SendDate)
        .First())
    .OrderBy(c => c.SendDate);
```

Answer (score 1):

This should give what you need:

```
_dbContext.chatTable
  .GroupBy(c => c.ProjectId)
  .Select(g => g.OrderBy(c => c.SendDate).LastOrDefault())
```